# Can't connect to SQL Server 2008 from .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, and uninstalled 2005 as a consequence my .net application with  a local SQL Server express doesn’t work anymore. I tried with nothwind 2008 sample at my App_Data folder. The connection string is :

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

When I try to connect to the file and testing the connection I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

I verified the security setting of the file and put everyone full control. What setting should I update in order to be able to open 2008 version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that SQL Server instance is running in the local machine?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I open service on my Windows XP and couldn't see MS SQL server at all. I open the sqlserver Configuration Manager, but don't see how to start the service. Could you please let me know how can I run the SQL server instance on XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to `Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager`

Check whether all the services are running or not. If not, start them. If yes, try to restart them once.
And see if it works.

Comment: There is no `Microsoft SQL Server 2008` item in `Control Panel`. Often there is such start menu item..

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but on my Config Manager the list of SQL Server services is empty. It says "There are no items to show in this view". I believe I didn't install correctly the Sql server client side. Which part should I reinstall in order to get this working correctly. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like when you uninstalled 2005, you uninstalled everything, including the database engine for SQL 2005.  If you want SQL 2008, you can install that using the Web Platform Installer:  http://www.microsoft.com/web/

Comment: No i reinstalled the 2008 samples.

Comment: I don't understand "2008 samples"  You need to install SQL Server Express 2008.

Comment: I did. I have Microsoft SQl Server 2008 on my All Programs List

Comment: That doesn't actually mean that you have installed the server portion of SQL Server 2008.  If it isn't showing up in your services list, then it isn't installed (correctly).

Comment: I reinstalled again SQL server 2008 this time with all services, and I see the SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) running int he service. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your services to ensure the SQL server instance is running.

**Edit**

I'm trying to get a handle on the issue.

Do you have a SQL Server Service listed under services? Run...services.msc or navigate via control panel. I believe during your uninstall/install something went awry and you will need to reinstall.

Comment: This is not an answer. Use comment instead of Post Answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I open service on my Windows XP and couldn't see MS SQL server at all. I open the sqlserver Configuration Manager, but don't see how to start the service. Could you please let me know how can I run the SQL server instance on XP?